# Jenkins url change

Tags: jenkins, hudson

Currently, we have Jenkins on a Ubuntu 10.04.3 VM. The url for this is `http://jenkins.myorg.com:8080/`.

Now we need to setup another Jenkins for different project. For that, I cloned above VM and changed its hostname to Jenkins2. Now how to set url for this new vm to like `http://jenkins2.myorg.com:8080/`.

I am able to access this new Jenkins using its `ipaddress:8080.`

Answer (score 22):

In `Manage Jenkins > Configure System` there's a field `Jenkins URL` where you can specify exactly that.

Comment: I tried that, but it is not working: getting page not found error.

Comment: Sounds like DNS or the networking of the VM isn't configured correctly.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff when i changed url getting **HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found**